# SQLPLUS Column Format and Select query executed simultaneously

Tags: sqlplus

I was curious if there was a way in SQLPLUS to run the column format option as well as the select query in one line? instead of having to run each format column line individually. for example:

```
((column "Role" heading "Role" Format a30, 
column "User ID" heading "User ID" Format a5, 
column "Password" heading "Password" format a8, 
column "Group" heading "Group" format a50, 
column "User Name" heading "User Name" Format a15),
(Select ...);
```

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COLUMN ... FORMAT command keeps config for a given column until either you exit from SQL*Plus or provide a new format. So NO, it does not apply to a single query and it cannot go inside a single query.

[(Oracle reference)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm)

Comment: Makes sense, Thanks for the info!